# Jmeter 2.10 HTTP recorder throws keytool exception

Tags: java, apache, jmeter

I am trying to investigate jmeter and have quickly run into some problems. I am attempting to follow the tutorial at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf. When I attempt to start the recorder I get a cannot create proxy error. The logs give me this message:

```
2013/10/23 13:40:54 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS 
2013/10/23 13:40:54 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread 
2013/10/23 13:54:32 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not open/read key store C:\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin\proxyserver.jks (The system cannot find the file specified) 
2013/10/23 13:54:32 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Creating Proxy CA in C:\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2013/10/23 13:54:32 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "keytool" (in directory "C:\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I don't know why the exe would not be picked up as it is part of java and in my path or why the jmeter zip would exclude a necessary file so I copied keytool from my java install into the directory it was looking for it and tried again. when I did I got this:

> ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store java.io.IOException:

I received a code of `-1073741515`, which as a beginner is not helpful. I tried these things with and without pointing to my proxy server, no difference in the results. I am on a windows 7 system 64 bit, and am using jdk 1.7.

Any suggestions on what steps I can take to correct the issue?

**Edit: here is the complete log**

```
    2013/10/23 15:34:06 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US   
2013/10/23 15:34:06 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: C:\apache-jmeter-.10\bin\user.properties   
2013/10/23 15:34:06 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: C:\apache-meter-2.10\bin\system.properties   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2013 The Apache Software Foundation   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.10 r1533061   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.7.0_21   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows 7   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=6.1   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States)   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States)   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=C:\apache-jmeter-2.10   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =C:\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =C:\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: xxxxxxxx Name: xxxxx FullName: xxxxx   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'   
2013/10/23 15:34:07 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform]   
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22   
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default   
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is    
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is    
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is    
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is    
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser   
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.WebServiceSamplerGui   
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui   
2013/10/23 15:34:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file C:\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin\proxyserver.jks   
2013/10/23 15:34:09 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times   
2013/10/23 15:34:09 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1   
2013/10/23 15:34:09 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true   
2013/10/23 15:34:09 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000   
2013/10/23 15:34:22 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not open/read   key store C:\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin\proxyserver.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)   
2013/10/23 15:34:22 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Creating Proxy CA in C:\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin\proxyserver.jks   
2013/10/23 15:34:22 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "keytool" (in directory "C:\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified  
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.SystemCommand.run(SystemCommand.java:142)
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.SystemCommand.run(SystemCommand.java:125)
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.genkeypair(KeyToolUtils.java:123)
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateProxyCA(KeyToolUtils.java:181)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initDynamicKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1275)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1205)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.startProxy(ProxyControl.java:431)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.startProxy(ProxyControlGui.java:485)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.actionPerformed(ProxyControlGui.java:370)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: I updated my answer, can you restart, if it still doesn't work ask on jmeter user mailing list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since JMeter 2.10, recording has been improved to better handle embedded resources and creation of certificates on the fly.
This makes recording complex HTTPS websites much easier.

To add these features, JMeter now uses keytool utility (available in JDK) so you need to ensure your configuration is correct, read this wiki page before starting:

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210

Also ensure you read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

Note it is much better to use a JDK7. (jdk7 should be installed on the system)

If you don't want to read the long answer (which you should :-) ), then:
Ensure you have JAVA_HOME and PATH set correctly, to do it:
Open jmeter.bat and add this (at the top after launch.exe command):

> SET JAVA_HOME=Path to JDK
>
> SET PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Restart JMeter and retest.

If it doesn't work, you can workaround by defining the following JMeter property in user.properties:

> proxy.cert.alias=anything

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. So I updated java, I was on 1.7.0_21 which I am guessing should have been fine to 1.7.0_45. "java -version" works fine, attempting "java keytool" does not. navigating to keytools directory and trying "java keytool" does not either. while in the directory if I run the command "keytool" I will get the list of commands info you would expect. Given java -version is working wouldn't it seem that java is working? do I need to setup another system variable or something?

Comment: it looks like disablement works and may allow me to continue experimenting, but I would like to set things up the "right way". +1 for the tidbit that will allow me to at least explore jmeter

Comment: If you have several JDKs, one of them might already be on the path and provide the wrong version of keytool, so putting the JDK to the beginning of PATH might be a better idea:

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 3):

Try running JMeter from a command prompt with admin privs, works for me !

Comment: Then I've got other error: ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt' does not exist
What do I have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the version JMeter 2.10, you must configure the var PATH in Windows.

The problem become from new PROXY HTTPS.

To avoid configuration of JMeter and JDK from Oracle, I make a package for installation.

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmeterforwindows/

A new package was created for JMeter 2.11

Answer (score -1):

Also I would recommend you to consider alternatives in automatic script writing. 
Actually there are some ways of .jmx scripts writing:

1. using proxy as described in the tutorial you've given
2. using badBoy tool .

   http://www.badboy.com.au/
   http://www.badboysoftware.biz/docs/
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OX9NbYuE07I

   benefits: easy record, easy export to jmeter.
3. using blazemeter chrome extenstion:

   http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/231479-chrome-extension

   benefits: You can export the script written to jmeter and/or to cloud as well and run it on the  cloud.

   As soon as you try these approaches probably you'll find out what you've missed.