# Jmeter 2.10, proxyserver.jks error

Tags: java, jmeter

I was getting error of SSL certification with Jmeter 2.9, after trying many options,
I have installed Jmeter 2.10 but in jmeter and I am getting proxyserver.jks file error.

After setting property in Jmeter.properties file I got message 'Proxy up and running!'

But when I hit google site in mozilla it is giving error in Jmeter for 'Exception when processing sample java.io.IOException: Unable to negotiate SSL transaction, no keystore?'

And even google site gives error 'Secure Connection Failed'

Please help me with this error

Thanks,
Bhavana

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550472/jmeter-2-10-http-recorder-throws-keytool-exception

Answer (score 1):

Since JMeter 2.10, recording has been improved to better handle embedded resources and creation of certificates on the fly. This make recording complex HTTPS websites much easier.

To add these features, JMeter now uses keytool utility (available in JDK) so you need to ensure your configuration is correct, read this wiki page before starting:

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210

Note it is much better to use a JDK7.

Also ensure you read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

And see:

- [Jmeter 2.10 HTTP recorder throws keytool exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550472/jmeter-2-10-http-recorder-throws-keytool-exception)