# Open/Read Key Store proxyserver.jks

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I saw the other forums and I performed the steps by setting the Path, etc. but it still doesn't work for me.  Side note jMeter is installed on a remote desktop machine for us.  I noticed that my error is displaying `users\psoliz\desktop\apache....` while the other users questions were just the `C:\apache...`. Please help.

```
2013/12/10 14:48:49 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not open/read key store C:\Users\psoliz\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin\proxyserver.jks (The system cannot find the file specified) 
2013/12/10 14:48:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Creating Proxy CA in C:\Users\psoliz\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2013/12/10 14:48:49 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "keytool" (in directory "C:\Users\psoliz\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.10\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question is here:

- [Jmeter 2.10 HTTP recorder throws keytool exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550472/jmeter-2-10-http-recorder-throws-keytool-exception)

I suggest you remove your question and upvote both question and answer mentionned below to avoid duplication.

Answer (score -1):

Keytool lives under JAVA_HOME/bin, not under JMETER_HOME/bin.

There is a guide on how to properly [record HTTPS traffic with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)