# Error starting proxy server in Apache JMeter

Tags: proxy, jmeter, ca

When I attempt to start a proxy server in JMeter I'm presented with the following error:

> could not create script recording proxy -see log for details: Command:'keytool -genkeypair alias :root_ca: -dname "CN=_DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate (JMeter root CA), OU=Username: root, C=IE" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass {redacted -keypass {redacted) -validity 7 -ext bc:c' failed, code: 1
>
> illegal option: -ext
>
> Try keytool -help

My proxy configuration:
[image]
Any suggestions?

Comment: try running the keytool command in a terminal or command prompt, you have got the options incorrect. CLI will be more informative of the error. Currently it is telling you that option -ext is not valid. keytool has no option -ext (do you mean -export).  Looks like you have other characters missing (did you mean alias or -alias). Try explaining what you want to happen, and then list the command you think will do that. jmeter is not your problem, keytool is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding the 'Path to JDK' in your start up script (jmeter.bat) -
before invoking java.exe

```
if .%JM_LAUNCH% == . set JM_LAUNCH=java.exe
```

Try this for .bat file

```
Set JAVA_HOME= /path/to/JDK
Set PATH = %PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin
if .%JM_LAUNCH% == . set JM_LAUNCH=java.exe
```

For .sh file,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/JDK
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
java $JVM_ARGS -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -jar `dirname $0`/ApacheJMeter.jar "$@"
```