# Jmeter 2.10 and 2.11 don't let me start a HTTP Script Recorder

Tags: proxy, jmeter, darwin

I'm having trouble starting a proxy server for jmeter 2.10 and 2.11.  I found a couple links [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550472/jmeter-2-10-http-recorder-throws-keytool-exception) and [apache.org](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210) but my error message is slightly different that what's written on these links.  Per the wiki from apache.org, I don't think I have trouble finding `keytool` because it returns the path when I do a

```
which keytool
/usr/bin/keytool
```

and  I don't have trouble creating a file in the jmeter-210 and jmeter-211/bin dirs.  This is the error message I get in my jmeter.log file:

```
ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store java.io.IOException: Command :'"keytool" "-genkeypair" "-alias" ":root_ca:" "-dname" "CN=_ DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate (JMeter root CA), OU=Username: COMPANY\user.name, C=US" "-keyalg" "RSA" "-keystore" "proxyserver.jks" "-storepass" "randomstr1" "-keypass" "randomstr1" "-validity" "7" "-ext" "bc:c"' failed, code: 1
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid escaped character in AVA: 's'
```

I don't know what this "invalid escaped char in AVA" is.  My company and username don't have the string "AVA" and I didn't find it in any of the property files in jmeter-21x/bin.

Not sure if this is affecting it but I'm running jmeter from Darwin on a MBP, OSX 10.7.5.
JMeter 2.9 doesn't give me any proxy issues, although, I ran into other issues with it, which is why I tried using these 2 newer versions, which are giving me problems with the proxy server.  I'll try going down to 2.8 to see what happens but I'd rather not if I can help it.  That and I'm super curious what the issue is with 2.1x and my laptop.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**: The COMPANY/user.name part of the error message was changed this way to sanitize the error message, although, I will try at home on my linux box to see if the funny username representation is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per sebb response on User Mailing List:

"I suspect it might be in the string "COMPANY\user.name" which is
derived from the Java system property "user.name".
You could try redefining it on the command line (or in
system.properties) to something simpler, for example:

-Duser.name=foobar

A bug has been opened to fix this issue with "\" character:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56178

Comment: Thx for your help and for roaming both the jmeter mailing list and SO to help ppl like me.  I guess I should have been more clear, I just "sanitized" the COMPANY/username part of the error msg b/c it displayed my company and username, although, I'll try this out at home on my linux box to see if it's due to Darwin and/or my company's way to represent our username on Darwin/Mac.

Comment: The issue is in the \ in fact

Comment: Thanks for confirming and continuing to look into this issue.  Also thanks for narrowing down the cause of the issue.  I also tried at home on my Centos box and I had no problems using the http recorder.

Comment: In this case, everything was done for sebb, so Thank him on mailing list. I just reported here in case anybody faces same issue. It is in Community Wiki so that I don't earn points